# How can i get jsapi.jar

Tags: java, python, jython, cmusphinx

im developing an application that uses CMU Sphinx4, but when i trying to run PythonTranscriber the following error occurs:

```
[root@karen python]# java -cp /home/karen/jython2.5/jython.jar:$CLASSPATH org.python.util.jython PythonTranscriber.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PythonTranscriber.py", line 36, in <module>
    from edu.cmu.sphinx.jsapi import JSGFGrammar
ImportError: No module named jsapi
```

i noticed that  the directory :`"/home/karen/sphinx4-1.0beta5-scr2/sphinx4-1.0beta/lib"`
does not have the jsapi.jar.
i tried to look for it in another directory but i can not find it.

How can i get jsapi.jar inside the directory :`"/home/karen/sphinx4-1.0beta5-scr2/sphinx4-1.0beta/lib"`
it supposed to be there!
Please help!

Answer (score 2):

It appears that it comes with Sphinx-4. See [this installation tutorial](http://www.robbrewer.me/projects/speechlion/INSTALL.html).

The basic instructions:

Download the [Sphinx-4 1.0beta4 package](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/sphinx4/1.0%20beta4/sphinx4-1.0beta4-bin.zip/download) from SourceForge.

Then, run the following:

```
unzip sphinx4-1.0beta4-bin.zip
cd sphinx4-1.0beta4-bin/lib
sh jsapi.sh
```

You'll need to accept the BCL license agreement which appears on the screen (scroll to the end, and then press 'y') which will unpack `jsapi.jar`.

Comment: when i trying to accept the BCL : Accept (y/n)?: 
y
x - creating lock directory
x - extracting jsapi.jar (binary)
jsapi.sh: line 257: uudecode: command not found
restore of jsapi.jar failed
jsapi.jar: MD5 check failed
my installation fails or is ok?

Answer (score 0):

After bit of Googling around (and cursing) I ended up at:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/jsapifaq-135248.html#implementation

which points you to a list of folks who provide implementations of the JSAPI.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same error. All you have to do is install **sharutils**. In my case, I was using Redhat 6, so 'sudo yum install sharutils' should install sharutils and you should be able to run 'sh jsapi.sh' with out any errors.